# Profiles on Top Network Askers panel are blurred

Tags: bug, profile-picture, top-network-posts

The profile pictures on the [Top Network Askers (right side)](https://stackexchange.com/) have always looked awfully blurry. why is that?

I'm not sure if it's a bug or intentionally done

As [Ilmari Karonen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/174699/ilmari-karonen) [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306136/profiles-on-top-network-askers-pane-are-blurred?noredirect=1#comment995185_306136):

> They're 16 x 16 pixel images, shown at 30 x 30 px

That's why it's blurred, so, why are we using 16x16 images? :/

Some Examples:

[image: Image showing Top Network Askers]

[image: Image showing Top Network Askers]

[image]

[image: they are all so blurry]

[image: Image showing Top Network Askers]

Comment: They're 16 x 16 pixel images, shown at 30 x 30 px...

Comment: That's just it, I wonder why it's using 16x16 images in the first place.

Comment: No idea. Probably they were 16x16 in some old version of the design, and somebody forgot to change the URLs when they changed the style sheet to make them bigger.

Comment: Almost a decade later Lol

Comment: Anyway, here's a quick JS hotfix: `$('.users-sidebar .userDetails img[src*="?s=16&"]').each(function () { this.src = this.src.replace(/\?s=16&/, '?s=30&') } )`. Just run that in the JS console and watch the images magically get sharper. :)

Comment: Thanks, I added it to my tampermonkey.